# Linq sql - where should I put phrase with "where"

Tags: linq

This is my query, an it almost works. I need to add to this query " where(k.IdUser == d.UserDoc.
The problem appears when I add this. Wherever I put this it stops working. **Join isn't option here.**

```
 var documents = (from d in DocumentDAO.GetDocument()
                         from k in UserDAO.GetUsers()
                         where (DateTime.Now <= d.ExpirationDate)
                         select new DocumentUI
                         {
                             Title = d.Title,
                             Description = d.Description,
                             DateOfAdd = d.DateOfAdd,
                             ExpirationDate = d.ExpirationDate,
                             UserDoc = d.UserDoc,
                             User = new UserUI {
                                FirstName = k.FirstName, 
                                LastName = k.LastName}

                         }).ToList();
```

My app gets the data from database and show this data in window. If I start my app with this query ( I have only one documents in db) it shows me the same document but with all Users, and I want to my application shows me only this user who Id is as foreign key in documents (UserDoc).

I tried somethig like this:

```
var documents = (from d in DocumentDAO.GetDocument()
                     from k in UserDAO.GetUsers()
                     where ((DateTime.Now <= d.ExpirationDate) && (d.UserDoc == k.IdUser))
                     select new DocumentUI
                     {
                         Title = d.Title,
                         Description = d.Description,
                         DateOfAdd = d.DateOfAdd,
                         ExpirationDate = d.ExpirationDate,
                         UserDoc = d.UserDoc,
                         User = new UserUI {
                            FirstName = k.FirstName, 
                            LastName = k.LastName}

                     }).ToList();
```

And:

```
var documents = (from d in DocumentDAO.GetDocument()
                     from k in UserDAO.GetUsers().Where(k => k.IdUser == d.UserDoc)
                     where (DateTime.Now <= d.ExpirationDate)
                     select new DocumentUI
                     {
                         Title = d.Title,
                         Description = d.Description,
                         DateOfAdd = d.DateOfAdd,
                         ExpirationDate = d.ExpirationDate,
                         UserDoc = d.UserDoc,
                         User = new UserUI {
                            FirstName = k.FirstName, 
                            LastName = k.LastName}

                     }).ToList();
```

and in both case my app shows me nothing

this it class DocumentUI:

```
public class DocumentUI
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfAdd { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public int UserDoc { get; set; }
    public UserUI User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, isn't it possible that there is just no user with `IdUser` equal to `d.UserDoc`? :)

Comment: No, in database I have fields like title, description, and one of this is who add and it's NOT NULL, and I check it, there is user ID

Comment: Perhaps try putting `UserDAO.GetUsers()` in a separate, materialized collection first, and then peek using a debugger to verify if at the moment code gets here this user indeed is retrieved.

Comment: I tried, nothing has changed

Comment: It wasn't supposed to change anything. It was supposed to provide you information I wrote about. So, what did you find?

Comment: If I do this debugger can't find match ID

Comment: So clearly you see that the problem doesn't lie in the way you compose your `where` statements...

Answer (score 0):

The below query (Same as your first Query) should return `List<DocumentUI>` provided you have proper data which satisfy `((DateTime.Now <= d.ExpirationDate) && (d.UserDoc == k.IdUser))`

```
var documents = (from d in DocumentDAO.GetDocument()
                 join k in UserDAO.GetUsers()
                 on d.UserDoc equals k.IdUser
                 where (d.ExpirationDate >= DateTime.Now)
                 select new DocumentUI
                 {
                     Title = d.Title,
                     Description = d.Description,
                     DateOfAdd = d.DateOfAdd,
                     ExpirationDate = d.ExpirationDate,
                     UserDoc = d.UserDoc,
                     User = new UserUI {
                        FirstName = k.FirstName, 
                        LastName = k.LastName}

                 }).ToList();
```

Still, If you are not getting result verify the values in `Var documents = DocumentDAO.GetDocument(), var users = UserDAO.GetUsers()`.

Comment: and like I said, join is not and option (my task reqiures it), besides, I just tried it, and It wont change it